# MongoDB returns array of "m" objects?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meteor, ngresource

I have setup backend with NodeJS and MongoDB. In frontend, I am using AngularJS and ngResource. When I run this block of code:

```
$scope.users = User.query(function() {
    console.log($scope.users);
});
```

it returns this:

[image]

What those 'm' letters mean? All of those are objects including the right data, so it works, I was just thinking what does this mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the name of the constructor that created the object. You can also see this below those values with `Promise` and `Array`.